# Is is possible to iterate through a series of letters and numbers longer than one character in a linux loop?

Tags: bash, scripting

In Linux is it possible to iterate through a series of letters or numbers more in a length of more than one?

Ex: `AAA,AAB...ZZY,ZZZ` or `000...999`, keeping the zeros in place

I understand that you can do:

```
for letter in {a..z}
```

but you cant legally add more chars, is there a way to do this without triple nested loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
for string in {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}; do
    # use "$string" here
done
```

This loop would iterate 17576 times (26*26*26 times).

To create all zero-filled number between `000` and `999`, you may use `{000..999}` in `bash` release 4 or later.

In earlier releases of `bash`, you may possibly want to use the same technique as is used with the loop above.

Or, you could use

```bash
for number in {0..999}; do
    printf -v znumber '%.3d' "$number"

    # use "$znumber" here
done
```

where `znumber` is created via a `printf` format which explicitly zero-fills an integer to three positions from `$number`.

Answer (score 2):

Tack on two more expansions:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | head -n 5
aaa
aab
aac
aad
aae
$ printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | tail -n 5
zzv
zzw
zzx
zzy
zzz
```

Bash supports padded expansion for numbers:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {000..999}  | head -n 5
000
001
002
003
004
```